Resolver problema de error stray \302 \240
tengo un problema con ese tal stray el cual no entiendo porque sale o porque, según investigando tiene que ver con caracteres especiales o algo así pero yo no ando usando ninguno de esos, necesito comprobar un ejercicio que me paso un compañero de clase pero no me funciona, soy el unico al que este ejercicio no le compila ni ejecuta y no sé que hacer, espero puedan ayudarme

Veo tu código de la foto y no veo nada extraño. Intenta poner mas código, pero en texto para que nosotros podamos modificarlo y ver cual es el problema

He investigado un poco y puede ser que en tu archivo haya un conflicto con las codificación de caracteres.

Recomiendo este programa: hdx - Hex Editor. Ha, y una lectura que explique un poco esto: Error \302\240. La explicaria pero no entiendo del todo el error

@DABL03 no val mal encaminado, el error lo tienes en la linea 71 (antepenúltima linea, linea que no muestras...., pero que seguro parece estar vacía cuando no lo está...) 302 240 es 0xC2 0xA0 en hexadecimal, justo la codificación del espacio duro (NO-BREAK SPACE) en UTF-8. Todo parece indicar que tienes una línea 71 rellenita de espacios duros, elimina esa linea o esos caracteres (los editores suelen tener una opción para mostrar espacios en blanco). ¿Por casualidad no te habrán pasado ese código a través de algún chat online o algo parecido?

El detalle es que este mensaje de error de compilación está apuntando a la línea 71. Tendrá que eliminar el carácter no ASCII. Como no compartió el código completo para replicarlo, entenderlo y localizar el error, se supone que digitó un carácter que no está incluido en la tabla ASCII.
